Unecessary checks before calling `\cs_if_exist_use:cTF`?
Consider this wrapper as an example:
\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \check_engine:n{p,T,F,TF}{
    \tl_trim_spaces_apply:nN{#1}\__check_engine:n
}
\cs_new:Npn \__check_engine:n #1{
    \bool_lazy_any:nTF{
        {\tl_if_blank_p:n{#1}}
        {\tl_if_novalue_p:n{#1}}
        {!\int_if_zero_p:n{\str_count_spaces:n{#1}}}
    }{\prg_return_false:}{
        \cs_if_exist_use:cTF{sys_if_engine_#1:TF}{
            {\prg_return_true:}{\prg_return_false:}
        }{\prg_return_false:}
    }
}
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \check_engine:n{e}{p,T,F,TF}

which can then be called in the following manner:
\check_engine{pdftex}{TRUE}{FALSE}
\check_engine{luatex}{TRUE}{FALSE}

I have 3 questions:

Question 1: Is the following, the right syntax for \cs_if_exist_use:cTF
\cs_if_exist_use:cTF{sys_if_engine_#1:TF}{{\prg_return_true:}{\prg_return_false:}}{\prg_return_false:}

Question 2: If I remove the current tests in \bool_lazy_any:nTF do I have the guarantee to have the exact same observable behaviour for all inputs? If not what tests can I get rid of?

Question 3: How to improve this code, and what would be the best/cleanest way to achieve what this code is doing?



why do you need all that aren't you just defining \check_engine:n to be \cs_use:c{sys_if_engine_#1:TF} ?

What exactly should your check do?

You seem to want to check whether the first argument

is not blank;
is not -NoValue-;
hasn't spaces in it;
corresponds to an engine that's supported by expl3, which is tested by the existence of \sys_if_engine_<argument>:TF.

Point 4 should not be confused with checking whether the currently employed engine coincides with the string given in the argument.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \check_engine:n {p,T,F,TF}
  {
    \tl_trim_spaces_apply:nN{#1}\__check_engine:n
  }
\cs_new:Nn \__check_engine:n
  {
    \bool_lazy_any:nTF
      {
        {\tl_if_blank_p:n{#1}}
        {\tl_if_novalue_p:n{#1}}
        {!\int_if_zero_p:n{\str_count_spaces:n{#1}}}
        {!\cs_if_exist_p:c{sys_if_engine_#1:TF}}
      }
      {\prg_return_false:}
      {\prg_return_true:}
  }
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \check_engine:n{e}{p,T,F,TF}

\check_engine:nTF{pdftex}{\iow_term:n{TRUE}}{\iow_term:n{FALSE}}
\check_engine:nTF{luatex}{\iow_term:n{TRUE}}{\iow_term:n{FALSE}}
\check_engine:nTF{pdf~tex}{\iow_term:n{TRUE}}{\iow_term:n{FALSE}}
\check_engine:nTF{}{\iow_term:n{TRUE}}{\iow_term:n{FALSE}}
\check_engine:nTF{foo}{\iow_term:n{TRUE}}{\iow_term:n{FALSE}}

\stop

This will show on the terminal
TRUE
TRUE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE

However, this is just checking whether \sys_engine_<argument>:TF exists, isn't it?
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \check_engine:n {p,T,F,TF}
  {
   \cs_if_exist:cTF{sys_if_engine_#1:TF}
    {\prg_return_true:}
    {\prg_return_false:}
  }
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \check_engine:n{e}{p,T,F,TF}

\check_engine:nTF{pdftex}{\iow_term:n{TRUE}}{\iow_term:n{FALSE}}
\check_engine:nTF{luatex}{\iow_term:n{TRUE}}{\iow_term:n{FALSE}}
\check_engine:nTF{pdf~tex}{\iow_term:n{TRUE}}{\iow_term:n{FALSE}}
\check_engine:nTF{}{\iow_term:n{TRUE}}{\iow_term:n{FALSE}}
\check_engine:nTF{foo}{\iow_term:n{TRUE}}{\iow_term:n{FALSE}}

\stop

If you want to trim leading or trailing spaces:
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \check_engine:n {p,T,F,TF}
  {
   \cs_if_exist:cTF{sys_if_engine_\tl_trim_spaces:n{#1}:TF}
    {\prg_return_true:}
    {\prg_return_false:}
  }
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \check_engine:n{e}{p,T,F,TF}

\check_engine:nTF{pdftex}{\iow_term:n{TRUE}}{\iow_term:n{FALSE}}
\check_engine:nTF{luatex}{\iow_term:n{TRUE}}{\iow_term:n{FALSE}}
\check_engine:nTF{~xetex~}{\iow_term:n{TRUE}}{\iow_term:n{FALSE}}
\check_engine:nTF{pdf~tex}{\iow_term:n{TRUE}}{\iow_term:n{FALSE}}
\check_engine:nTF{}{\iow_term:n{TRUE}}{\iow_term:n{FALSE}}
\check_engine:nTF{foo}{\iow_term:n{TRUE}}{\iow_term:n{FALSE}}

\stop

will produce
TRUE
TRUE
TRUE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE

